# Algorithm to partially sort list into equal-sized buckets

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Suppose I have a large list of numbers that I want to divide into equal-sized buckets so that every bucket contains only larger numbers than buckets to its left. Numbers within each bucket don't need to be sorted.

For example, for the input

```
[64, 72, 57, 47, 5, 4, 64, 21, 64, 65, 36, 43, 81, 44, 19, 87, 17, 86, 
 73, 21, 19, 64, 94, 91, 34, 49, 8, 52, 18, 37]
```

that I want to divide into 5 buckets, some valid outputs would be

```
[[4, 5, 8, 17, 18], [19, 19, 21, 21, 34], [36, 37, 43, 44, 47], 
 [49, 52, 57, 64, 64], [64, 64, 65, 72, 73]]

[[8, 17, 18, 5, 4], [21, 19, 21, 34, 19], [43, 37, 44, 36, 47], 
 [52, 57, 49, 64, 64], [64, 64, 72, 73, 65]]

[[8, 18, 5, 4, 17], [19, 19, 21, 21, 34], [47, 36, 44, 43, 37], 
 [52, 64, 49, 64, 57], [64, 72, 64, 65, 73]]

[[18, 8, 17, 5, 4], [21, 19, 21, 19, 34], [36, 44, 43, 37, 47], 
 [57, 64, 64, 49, 52], [64, 72, 64, 65, 73]]
```

One approach to do this would be to sort the list, and then divide it at equal intervals. Can this be done faster?

I would also be happy with a result where the buckets are of only roughly equal size, but note that I can't assume a uniform distribution for the numbers, so bucket sort doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to create $k$ buckets, to the following.

1. [Obtain elements of rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) $\lceil n/k \rceil, 2 \cdot \lceil n/k \rceil \dots, (k-1) \cdot \lceil n/k \rceil$.
2. Perform multi-way partitioning (cf. Quicksort) with these elements as pivot.

Both steps take time $\Theta(kn)$. All buckets are within $\pm 1$ of the same size.

In the case of duplicate elements, you can "uniquify" them in a $\Theta(n)$ preprocessing run; otherwise bucket sizes might differ more.

Essentially, this is performing only the top-level call of a $k$-way Quicksort with perfect pivots. All variants regarding pivot selection and partitioning apply and will lead to different runtime and bucket size characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of this off the top of my head.   You could try to use a B+ tree, with number of pointers $m=k$, where $k$ is your bucket size.

The leaves would be your partitioned buckets.  If you went from the list to the B+ tree, then each insert is $O(log_k(n))$ and for n items, it would take $O(n*log_k(n))$ for inserting the entire list.  If you are using a B+ tree you happen to have direct access to the B+ structure, you could just collect the pointer to the leaf nodes.

You could also just get rid of the list altogether sacrificing a $O(1)$ insertion to have the buckets already created for you in the B+ tree in $O(1)$.

One down side, is that the buckets may not be full, but they will be partially ordered.

Comment: How does that beat sorting and splitting? Same (asymptotic) runtime.